# Multiple while loops not functioning

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have this `while` loop in my product page with Wordpress e-commerce plugin. It is looping through custom post meta.

```
<?php if (wpsc_have_custom_meta()) : ?>
    <?php $count = 2; ?>
    <?php while ( wpsc_have_custom_meta() ) : wpsc_the_custom_meta(); ?>
    <?php if (stripos(wpsc_custom_meta_name(),'g:') !== FALSE) continue; ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo wpsc_custom_meta_name(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php $count ++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I repeat this twice. Once to iterate through tab titles and once through the tab body. But for some reason the second instance of the `while loop` won't work. If I delete the first instance then the second one works as expected but as soon as I have to examples of it then it no longer works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have to assume the problem is with how those `wpsc_*` functions work. My guess is that they are looping over an array/object and not resetting at the end. As those are not core functions, though, this is going to be off-topic as being dependent upon third-party code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear possible to loop over the values multiple times without directly manipulating the `current_custom_meta` class var so that `wpsc_have_custom_meta()` will return `true` again. Give this a try before the second while loop:

```
global $wpsc_custom_meta;
$wpsc_custom_meta->rewind_custom_meta();
$wpsc_custom_meta->current_custom_meta = -1;
```